# nssm is not rotating output files

Tags: nssm

I am using the below parameters for creating windows service. However, the nssm is not rotating the output file:

```
AppRotateFiles 1(enables file rotation)

AppRotateOnline 0

AppRotateSeconds 86400 (time between rotation)

AppRotateBytes 1048576 (file size threshold to rotate the file)
```

Comment: please have you a solution to keep only the last backup file

Answer (score 0):

Without online rotation turned on NSSM only rotates the files when the service starts. If you just have it running it will not do anything.